# "Ich halte die Flasche in die Luft." Warum denn den Akkusativ?

Tags: grammar

In [einer](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-weil-das-ist-ein-nebensatz-a-350013.html) der immer amüsanten Kolumnen von *Zwiebelfisch* lese ich den Satz:

> "Will noch jemand Wasser?", frage ich und halte die Sprudelflasche in die Luft.

Ich bin natürlich 100% sicher, daß er richtig ist, aber warum steht da nicht *...die Flasche in der Luft*?
 Für mich als französischen Muttersprachler ist *halten* rein statisch und sollte also den Dativ regieren.
Was ist los (und könnte man auch *in der Luft* sagen)?

**Metafrage**
Ist mein Titel korrekt oder sollte es *Warum denn der Akkusativ?* heißen? :-)

Comment: Zum Titel: Ich würde *Warum denn Akkusativ?* schreiben (klingt besser). *den* ist jedoch nicht falsch, denn man könnte gedanklich ein Verb hinzufügen wie in *Warum denn den Akkusativ nehmen?*

Comment: @splattne: Mir fehlt das Verb sehr, und dem Satz m.E. auch. Das fehlende Satzzeichen vor dem 'Warum' verschärft die Situation noch. Erst nach 3maligem Lesen und Lesen des Textes erschließt sich langsam, was gemeint ist.

Comment: @splattne. Ach ja, in der Tat:  *Warum denn Akkusativ* klingt besser.

Comment: Mein Vorschlag für den Titel: Warum Akkusativ in "Ich halte die Flasche in die Luft".

Comment: @Em1: Da ein Smilie, oder auch nur wieder ein Verb? Es seit jüngst ein Verbverbot?

Comment: @userunknown Wir reden hier vom Titel. Kurz, prägnant, verständlich. Das fehlende Verb erschwert das Lesen nicht. Du kannst aber auch gerne schreiben "Warum verwenden wir anstatt des Dativs den Akkusativ in Sätzen wie "Ich halte die Flasche in die Luft". Dann kannst du dir direkt auch jeglichen Text in der Frage ersparen.

Comment: Liebe Freunde, man kann natürlich  unendlich viele Umformulierungen meines Titels finden. Ich wollte aber wissen, ob meine *unveränderte* Fassung richtig klingt **und** ob *Warum der Akkusativ ?* auch möglich wäre.

Comment: @Em1: Ich bin beim Lesen der Frage mehrfach über den Titel gestolpert, d.h. dass das fehlende Verb das Lesen sehr wohl erschwert. Mein Vorschlag war nicht, einen Roman daraus zu machen, sondern das fehlende Verb zu ergänzen. Wir sind hier auch nicht bei der Bildzeitung, sondern bei einem Sprachdienst.

Comment: @userunknown Nein, du bist wegen *denn* und *den* darüber gestolpert. Hätte da nur "Warum Akkusativ" gestanden, hättest du keine Schwierigkeiten gehabt.

Comment: @Em1: Zumindest kann man, wenn man mit der Länge der Überschrift argumentiert, das 'denn' opfern, um ein Verb aufzunehmen; 'verwenden' schlage ich vor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beim Jonglieren würde man sagen "Ich halte die Flasche in der Luft".

Ansonsten ist bei Richtungsangaben der Akkusativ üblich.

Comment: Danke für das interessante, kontrastierende Beispiel.Was den üblichen Akkusativ betrifft: das Problem ist, daß für mich nicht Muttersprachler das Verb  *halten* überhaupt keine Richtungsangabe beinhaltet.

Comment: Das ist aber eine andere Bedeutung von "halten" (engl. "keep" statt "hold").

Comment: Antwort wegen des Beispiels angenommen, welches zeigt, daß *in der Luft* in manchem Zusammenhang möglich  ist.

Answer (score 17):

Das Verb *halten* ist in dem Satz nicht als statische Tätigkeit zu verstehen, wie zum Beispiel  in folgender Aussage:

> Ich halte die Flasche in der linken Hand.

Im Satz der Frage oben ist *halten* hingegen als Tätigkeit gemeint – im Sinne von etwas *irgendwohin* bewegen. Deshalb ist es richtig, den Akkusativ für das Objekt zu verwenden.

Folgende Paraphrase macht das vielleicht etwas deutlicher:

> Ich nehme die Flasche und hebe sie in die Luft hoch.

---

**Update:**

Hier der [Eintrag im Online-Duden-Wörtbuch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halten#Bedeutung2a) dazu.
*(danke, Em1!)*

Answer (score 2):

> Ich halte die Flasche in der Luft

impliziert, dass du die Flasche bereits in die Luft gehalten hast und jetzt dran bist, sie in der Luft zu halten. Die Aktion ist bereits begonnen und wird weiterhin ausgeführt.

> Ich halte die Flasche in die Luft

dagegen impliziert, dass die die Flasche **jetzt** in die Luft hältst, du somit die Aktion jetzt beginnst.

Comment: Du gehst von einer *zeitlichen* Begründung des Falles aus - Akkusativ wird im Prinzip eher mit "Bewegung auf etwas zu", Dativ mit "statisch ruhend" verwendet.